# How to add plasmoids to the Latte dock?

Tags: kde, plasma

Is it possible to add [plasmoids](https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Plasma/Plasmoids) to the [latte dock](https://store.kde.org/p/1169519)? I have seen screenshots where this seems to have been done. I would be particularly interested in adding a keyboard layout indicator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Latte Dock 0.6.2**

Adding plasmoid

1. Start the Latte Dock - the Latte Dock application not the plasmoid

[image]
[image]

2. Start the plasma widget browser.
3. Drag and drop
   the plasmoid to the Latte Dock.

The keyboard layout indicator is part of the KDE System Tray.

[image]

Removing plasmoid

1. Enable the Latte Settings
2. Move the mouse over the plasmoid
3. Click the remove button

[image]

Comment: It sounds so obvious, but the slight difference between the dock application and the launcher got me...